# Is it a good idea to use pointer to stl vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

In Stanley Lippman's book there is an example, when he uses

```
vector <string> * var;
```

why does he create a pointer to vector?

Is it useful to create a pointer to vector sometimes?
When should I do so?

Comment: it's as useful as a pointer to anything else.

Comment: But vector's data is already in the heap. It seems to me that poiter to vector only adds problems delete. So what is the use in a pointer?

Comment: Probably, unless you supplied a fancy allocator. Even then it may be that you want to pass a vector around as a pointer, allocate it dynamically etc. (although raw pointers could be called rare pointers in modern C++, admittedly). Oh, and with modern C++ allowing to specify move semantics it's often not necessary any longer to pass vectors as pointers or references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers are not only useful for data on the heap, and not all pointers should be deleted.

Pointers are useful as a possibly-null reference to another object, for example you might need to call a function which has a pointer parameter, indicating that you can optionally pass a vector:

```
int frobnicate(std::string filename, std::vector<std::string>* words);
```

If I pass a non-null pointer as the second argument the function will store some data in `*words`.

I could call that like this:

```
int frob = frobnicate("input.txt", nullptr);
```

or like this:

```
std::vector<string> v;
std::vector<string>* pv = &v;
int frob = frobnicate("input.txt", pv);
```

Or I could avoid declaring `pv` by creating a temporary pointer just for the call: `frobnicate("input.txt", &v)` but I don't *have* to do that.

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed it is useful.

even more useful will be like this `unique_ptr<vector<string>> var ( new vector<string>)`

Comment: It would be even better, if you used `make_unique()`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to think about is, the lifetime of the vector<> object.

For example:

```
{
   vector<string> mstrs;
}
```

The object 'mstrs' went out of scope and the values in the container are unavailable for any further use.

You can extend this analysis to functions, which populate this vector. Do you want to return by value, thus incurring the copy cost or pass-by-ref of an object at the call-site.

Making a point to vector<>, gives you choices regarding lifetime management, independent of scoping rules. You may still want to take advantage of scoping, by using smart-pointers etc. That is a separate topic in itself.

As you mentioned, a pointer, certainly adds memory management - meaning you have to properly delete the object at an appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Two types of vector declaration and its mean: 
1) std::vector var;
    - For this declaration, Vector allocate memory for its elements on the heap and it's(allocated memory) address on stack. 
    - So for this reason number of elements is directly proportional to Stack size (And large stack size is not good  for programming, basically it is not suitable for small device programming).
2) std::vector *var = new vector();
    - For this declaration, Vector allocate memory for its elements and it's(allocated memory) address both on the heap.

This is one the reason that "why use pointer of vector?". 
Please let me know if i was getting it wrong way.

Thank you